# PHP Slim - using anonymous functions with a simple rest api

Tags: php, rest, slim

I have created a simple rest api which handles some POST data. I would like to add some functions to sanitize the data before sending a response.

I am new to Slim and PHP so unsure if this is possible / i am solving the problem using the "correct" approach.

Here is my attempt so far (which does not work!) The middleware is called, but the process function always returns NULL

```
<?php
use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new \Slim\App();


// add function to $app
$app->process = function ($request, $response, $next) use($app) {
    return 'process';
};

$process = $app->process;

// middleware
$mw = function ($request, $response, $next) {
    $response = $next($request, $response);   

    // should return string from above function
    $variable = $process

    $data = array('name' => $name, 'process' => $variable);
    $newResp = $response->withJson($data);
    return $newResp;
};


$app->post('/api/name', function (Request $request, Response $response, array $args) {
    $parsed= $request->getParsedBody();
    $response = $response->withStatus(200);
})->add($mw);

$app->run();
```

Answer (score 0):

There were several issues:

1. Added function to `$app` which results in a `BadMethodCallException`
2. `$app`already has a method called `process`
3. Missed `;` after `$variable = $process`

This code gives your desired result:

```
use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

// turn error logging on!
$app = new \Slim\App(['settings' => ['displayErrorDetails' => true]]);

// your function
$sanitize = function(){
  return 'process';
};

// middleware + pass function
$mw = function ($request, $response, $next) use($sanitize) {
  $response = $next($request, $response);

  $variable = $sanitize(); // execute function

  $data = array('name' => $name, 'process' => $variable);
  $newResp = $response->withJson($data);
  return $newResp;
};


$app->get('/api/name', function (Request $request, Response $response, array $args) {
  $parsed= $request->getParsedBody();
  $response = $response->withStatus(200);
})->add($mw);

$app->run();
```

When you don't need to use the functions in other middleware, you could simply define the functions in your middleware, like this:

```
// middleware
$mw = function ($request, $response, $next) use($sanitize) {
  $response = $next($request, $response);

  // your function
  function sanitize(){
    return 'process';
  }

  $data = array('name' => $name, 'process' => sanitize());
  $newResp = $response->withJson($data);
  return $newResp;
};
```